# Detect the point that cuts the line using arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management

Tags: arcpy, select-by-location

I have two layers, a linear one which represents cables, the second one is a layer of points representing optical connection points. My problem is that the points cut the cables in two during their integration on a software called NetDesigner.
I made a script to recover the duplicate cables and the integrated points that cut the cables with the information of the last user who added the point on the lineaire.
The problem with the results I get is that I get even the points that do not cut the cables.

Note: The cable that is cut is retrieved using the `REFERENCE` field in the attribute table.

Do you have any idea how to retrieve exactly the point that cuts the line in two and exclude the cases where the point just touches the line?

Here is my code:

```
couche_bpe = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(chem_bpe)
couche_cable = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(chem_caftth)
couche_pbo = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(chem_pbo)


champ_a_verfier = ["REFERENCE"]  
values={}
values["Ref_Nulle"]=0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(couche_cable, champ_a_verfier) as rows:
    for r in rows:
        if r[0] in [None,""]:
            values["Ref_Nulle"]+=1
        else:
            if r[0] not in values:
                values[r[0]]=1
            else:
                values[r[0]]+=1 
del rows

dictDoublons = {}
dictPasDoublons = {}
cable_cda = 'CDA'
count = 0
for item in values:
    if values[item] > 1 :
        if not item.startswith("CDA"):
            dictDoublons[item] = 'Doublons'
            count+=1
            arcpy.AddWarning('Il y a {} cables en doublons  a Verifier / Corriger.'.format(count))
    else:   
        dictPasDoublons[item] = 'PasDoublons'




#Recuperer les cables les plus proches des doublons
#Construction des élements nécessaires à la requête !
#construction de la chaine de caractère nécessaire a la requpete REFERENCE IN le but étant d'avoir  ("'CDI-47-GON2-097-1','CDI-47-GON2-097-1'")

liste_de_doublons = []
for key in dictDoublons:
    liste_de_doublons.append(key)

tuple_doublons = tuple(liste_de_doublons)

for i in tuple_doublons:
    resultat_selection = arcpy.management.SelectLayerByAttribute(couche_cable, "NEW_SELECTION", "REFERENCE in ('{:s}')".format("','".join(liste_de_doublons)))

resultat_selection_feature = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(resultat_selection)

select_pbo_cut_lines = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(pbo_feature,"WITHIN_A_DISTANCE",cable_coupe,0.02,"NEW_SELECTION")
arcpy.GetCount_management(select_pbo_cut_lines)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(select_pbo_cut_lines, "pbo_intersect")
```

Comment: No, i have to get the information of the point and send them to another team.

Comment: I joined the point layer to the cut cable layer. but the result is not differentiated. I get all the points that are 0.02 cm away from a linear. but I want to get only the points that cut the cable.

Comment: Try Near between end points of the lines and other points.